# Undefined Name when serializing extended class in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have the following classes in a flutter app I am developing.  The intent is to have an inheritable class (Includable) which is extended by Item (and some other similar classes, all generating the same error), with serializable members as part of the ancestor class:

includedcondition.dart:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'includecondition.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class IncludeCondition {
  String property;
  String condition;
  String selection;
  String value;

  IncludeCondition({this.property, this.condition, this.selection, this.value});

  // Serialization Methods
  factory IncludeCondition.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$IncludeConditionFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$IncludeConditionToJson(this);
}
```

includable.dart:

```
import 'package:randomizer/model/includecondition.dart';
import 'package:randomizer/model/setup.dart';

abstract class Includable {
  List<IncludeCondition> includedWhen;
  List<IncludeCondition> includedIf;
  List<IncludeCondition> mustIncludeWhen;
  List<IncludeCondition> excludeWhen;

  Includable();
}
```

item.dart:

```
import 'package:randomizer/model/includable.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:randomizer/model/includecondition.dart';

part 'item.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Item extends Includable {
  String name;

  Item({this.name, this.expansion, this.playerMin, this.playerMax, this.cost});

  // Serialization Methods
  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ItemFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ItemToJson(this);
}
```

When the project is built, I get "Undefined name 'IncludeCondition'" in the item.g.dart class, which has the following code:

```
Item _$ItemFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Item(
      name: json['name'] as String,
    ..includedWhen = (json['includedWhen'] as List)
        ?.map((e) => e == null
            ? null
            : IncludeCondition.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList()
    ..includedIf = (json['includedIf'] as List)
        ?.map((e) => e == null
            ? null
            : IncludeCondition.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList()
    ..mustIncludeWhen = (json['mustIncludeWhen'] as List)
        ?.map((e) => e == null
            ? null
            : IncludeCondition.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList()
    ..excludeWhen = (json['excludeWhen'] as List)
        ?.map((e) => e == null
            ? null
            : IncludeCondition.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList();
}
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `import 'includedcondition.dart;'` in your `item.dart` file.

Comment: I have updated my listing, but that import was already included in item.dart.